# Very slow internet speed in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet

I am using firefox/opera for browsing, tried wired/wireless connection but it does not change the situation. I have adsl router connected to asus router wich has wi-fi. I use a few devices in my home through wi-fi and they works fine. Previously I had windows installed on my pc and it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in DNS of my ISP. When I changed ISP DNS to Google DNS in my adsl router the web started to work flawless.